# Can Windows Media Player create playlists based on folder structure?

Tags: windows-7, video, music, windows-media-player

Over the years I've carefully molded my digital media collection into a series of folders that make it easy for me to find what I'm looking for. I recently discovered the awesomeness that is [streaming video from Windows 7 Media Player to the PS3](https://superuser.com/q/87533/35393) so I can watch it on the big screen without all the hassle of hooking the computer up to the TV. The problem is, I totally lose my carefully crafted folder structure and all my videos become one giant mess again... not cool! As a temporary solution, I've created a few playlists for my favorites (Dexter Season 4, Dexter Season 5, Breaking Bad Season 1, etc.). This is a HUGE pain in the a$$.

So, is there a way to get Windows Media Player (on Windows 7) to maintain some sort of folder structure based on the location of the actual video files? So if I have my videos sorted into folders by show and season, Media Player will pick that up and let me browse it in the same way.

As an alternative answer, I'll accept suggestions for a program that can also stream to PS3 and has this "folder organization" feature.

Comment: I would look into scripting it in WPSH

Comment: Is it possible to have nested playlists? Otherwise how could I maintain the nested folder structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother going for complex solutions, think logical steps ;)

Open Windows Media Player (WMP), and also open Windows Explorer.  From Windows Explorer, right-click the folder you want to add, then select 'Add to Windows Media Playerlist'.  WMP will add all songs in all subdirectories of that folder to a list.  You can then save and rename the utitled list.  It will be easy for you to later merge folder as you wish.

Why hasn't someone posted this solution before???? beats me?

(note this works for Windows 7, latest WMP version as of 13/01/2011)

Answer (score 2):

Not to seem like a condescending jerk, but I used to listen to my music based on file-system metadata like folders and file names just like you. There is a better way. Focus on getting the correct metadata into your files. For MP3s you should get all of your ID3 tags setup correctly using something like the [Picard tagger](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardTagger). The same principal should apply for your videos -- get the metadata right. Then you can use Windows Media Player, MediaMonkey, etc to create auto playlists for you that are exactly tailored to what you want to watch or listen to. For the cost of the initial investment in setting up your metadata correctly, you will be repaid many times over by the ability to make any playlist in seconds much more easily and flexibly than you can using your folder approach.

Comment: not condescending at all... good suggestion

Comment: Old post, but I had to respond. Sorry, but in my experience, it's *very* common for tags to be either incomplete or inconsistent with what you really want, and it's not reasonable to go through 1000's of tracks ensuring tags are correct. In the days when I used to organize my music, it made most sense to organize by folder hierarchically, esp. when the source and tags for the music was different eg rip vs download.  I get angry at the UI geniuses who don't recognize this and remove the ability to sort/view/play by directory structure.  Kudos to Winamp for allowing me to play by folder!

Answer (score 2):

Drag Folder to playlist, click "list options" on top right side of the playlist. The go down to "Sort list by", and select "File name".

Should help.

Answer (score 1):

MediaMonkey V4 has this feature (UPnP sharing by Location).  It's not yet released (in fact the beta program hasn't even begun), but if you want to try the development build, it's available at:
http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=54156

Disclosure: I work on MediaMonkey

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be setting folder and sub folders to Music type content. This will be effective when using single folder for all your music.

[image: Folder properties]

Answer (score 0):

in WMP  right click on Music in the navigation panel and then "customize navigation panel". In the music section check Folder.